# Display Entry and Exit sql records in one row and calculate the time between them

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following table (transactions table) and I am using MS SQL:

[image]

Now what I need to do is for each cardholder show the entry and the matching exit on the same row. So that they can see for how long the person was inside the building.

I have been trying to approach this in various ways but I can't get the information. Any suggestions as to how I can approach this will be greatly appreciated. I have been looking into the CTE approach but my issue is that I am having difficulties getting this to work.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name He didn't upload an image of his code. The image shows some data, they're different. Though it could be pasted as plain text too, but that requires good formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demonstrates how it might be done in Oracle. The `trans` with clause would of course be a real table in a real world scenario. For this SQL to work in other RDBMSes, you probably have to remove all `from dual` and change how the time strings are parsed and calculated on to get seconds for each visit. (Subtraction on two `DATE` date type values in Oracle leaves a floating point number for the number of days between them, hence *24*3600 to get seconds).

```
with
trans as (
  select 4 id, 'CT1' name, 54 tmhisid, 'Entry' caption, '2017-10-16 14:31:06' dt from dual union
  select 5 id, 'CT2' name, 55 tmhisid, 'Entry' caption, '2017-10-16 14:31:14' dt from dual union
  select 4 id, 'CT1' name, 56 tmhisid, 'Exit'  caption, '2017-10-16 14:47:00' dt from dual union
  select 5 id, 'CT2' name, 57 tmhisid, 'Exit'  caption, '2017-10-16 14:47:05' dt from dual union
  select 4 id, 'CT1' name, 58 tmhisid, 'Entry' caption, '2017-10-16 15:05:24' dt from dual union
  select 5 id, 'CT2' name, 59 tmhisid, 'Entry' caption, '2017-10-16 15:05:33' dt from dual union
  select 4 id, 'CT1' name, 60 tmhisid, 'Exit'  caption, '2017-10-16 15:10:25' dt from dual union
  select 5 id, 'CT2' name, 61 tmhisid, 'Exit'  caption, '2017-10-16 15:10:29' dt from dual
),
trans2 as ( select trans.*, to_date(dt,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') d from trans ),
entry as ( select * from trans2 where caption='Entry' ),
exit  as ( select * from trans2 where caption='Exit' ),
visit as (
  select en.id, en.name, en.d entry, ex.d exit
  from entry en
  join exit ex on ex.id=en.id
  where ex.d>=en.d
  and not exists (select 1 from exit ex2 where id=en.id and ex2.d>en.d and ex2.d<ex.d)
)
select visit.*, (exit-entry)*24*3600 sec from visit
order by entry;
```

Result:

```
  ID NAM ENTRY               EXIT                 SECONDS
---- --- ------------------- ------------------- --------
   4 CT1 2017-10-16 14:31:06 2017-10-16 14:47:00      954
   5 CT2 2017-10-16 14:31:14 2017-10-16 14:47:05      951
   4 CT1 2017-10-16 15:05:24 2017-10-16 15:10:25      301
   5 CT2 2017-10-16 15:05:33 2017-10-16 15:10:29      296
```

Comment: Hi, I thank you for your response. There has been a changed now where I can longer use the Exit or Entry captions. Is there any other way you could suggest to do this?

Comment: Search-replace every "exit" and "entry" in the SQL? (Nor sure what you're asking)

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, so what I have to do is for each cardholder show the entry and the matching exit on the same row. My issue is finding the way to be able to process all this data in a way that I can match transactions as "entry" and "exit".